# C++ equivalent of numpy.unique on std::vector with return_index and return_inverse

Tags: c++, numpy, stl

`numpy` has an implementation of the `unique` algorithm that returns :

1. the *sorted unique elements* of a numpy array (*i.e.* with no duplicates)

In addition, [numpy.unique()](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.unique.html) can also return :

2. the indices of the input array that give the unique values
3. the indices of the unique array that reconstruct the input array

The C++ standard library also implements  a `unique` algorithm ([here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/unique)), that somehow  eliminates consecutive duplicates. Combined with `std::vector<>::erase` and `std::sort()`, this can return the *sorted unique elements* of the vector (output 1 of `numpy.unique()`).

My question is : is there any algorithm in the `stl` or elsewhere that can also return  outputs 2 and 3 of `numpy.unique()`. If not, is there a way to efficiently implement it ?

Comment: Thanks for sharing this question. Really interesting. Just wanted to share numpy's python implementation source here, as a potential reference (even if it's not C++): https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/v1.22.0/numpy/lib/arraysetops.py#L138-L317 (especially lines 351-361 of the code).

Comment: AFAIK, no, the STL does not directly provide such an algorithm. However, you can write this yourself using the STL quite easily. Are you interested in such a solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a version that just uses one or two temporary vectors. Overall complexity is O(n log(n)) for n input values.

```
#include <algorithm>
// using std::stable_sort, std::unique, std::unique_copy
#include <iterator>
// using std::back_inserter
#include <vector>
// using std::vector


/** Helper to implement argsort-like behavior */
template<class T>
struct SortPair
{
  T value;
  std::size_t index;

  SortPair(const T& value, std::size_t index)
    : value(value), index(index)
  {}
  SortPair(T&& value, std::size_t index)
    : value(std::move(value)), index(index)
  {}
  bool operator<(const SortPair& o) const
  { return value < o.value; }

  bool operator<(const T& o) const
  { return value < o; }

  friend bool operator<(const T& left, const SortPair& right)
  { return left < right.value; }

  bool operator==(const SortPair& o) const
  { return value == o.value; }

  friend void swap(SortPair& left, SortPair& right)
  {
      using std::swap;
      swap(left.value, right.value);
      swap(left.index, right.index);
  }
};
/**
 * Implements numpy.unique
 *
 * \tparam T scalar value type
 * \tparam Iterator input iterator for type T
 * \param first, last range of values
 * \param index if not null, returns the first indices of each unique value in
 *    the input range
 * \param inverse if not null, returns a mapping to reconstruct the input range
 *    from the output array. first[i] == returnvalue[inverse[i]]
 * \param count if not null, returns the number of times each value appears
 * \return sorted unique values from the input range
 */
template<class T, class Iterator>
std::vector<T> unique(Iterator first, Iterator last,
                      std::vector<std::size_t>* index=nullptr,
                      std::vector<std::size_t>* inverse=nullptr,
                      std::vector<std::size_t>* count=nullptr)
{
  std::vector<T> uvals;
  if(! (index || inverse || count)) { // simple case
    uvals.assign(first, last);
    using t_iter = typename std::vector<T>::iterator;
    const t_iter begin = uvals.begin(), end = uvals.end();
    std::sort(begin, end);
    uvals.erase(std::unique(begin, end), end);
    return uvals;
  }
  if(first == last) { // early out. Helps with inverse computation
    for(std::vector<std::size_t>* arg: {index, inverse, count})
      if(arg)
        arg->clear();
    return uvals;
  }
  using sort_pair = SortPair<T>;
  using sort_pair_iter = typename std::vector<sort_pair>::iterator;
  std::vector<sort_pair> sorted;
  for(std::size_t i = 0; first != last; ++i, ++first)
    sorted.emplace_back(*first, i);
  const sort_pair_iter sorted_begin = sorted.begin(), sorted_end = sorted.end();
  // stable_sort to keep first unique index
  std::stable_sort(sorted_begin, sorted_end);
  /*
   * Compute the unique values. If we still need the sorted original values,
   * this must be a copy. Otherwise we just reuse the sorted vector.
   * Note that the equality operator in SortPair only uses the value, not index
   */
  std::vector<sort_pair> upairs_copy;
  const std::vector<sort_pair>* upairs;
  if(inverse || count) {
    std::unique_copy(sorted_begin, sorted_end, std::back_inserter(upairs_copy));
    upairs = &upairs_copy;
  }
  else {
    sorted.erase(std::unique(sorted_begin, sorted_end), sorted_end);
    upairs = &sorted;
  }
  uvals.reserve(upairs->size());
  for(const sort_pair& i: *upairs)
    uvals.push_back(i.value);
  if(index) {
    index->clear();
    index->reserve(upairs->size());
    for(const sort_pair& i: *upairs)
      index->push_back(i.index);
  }
  if(count) {
    count->clear();
    count->reserve(uvals.size());
  }
  if(inverse) {
    inverse->assign(sorted.size(), 0);
    // Since inverse->resize assigns index 0, we can skip the 0-th outer loop
    sort_pair_iter sorted_i =
      std::upper_bound(sorted_begin, sorted_end, uvals.front());
    if(count)
      count->push_back(std::distance(sorted_begin, sorted_i));
    for(std::size_t i = 1; i < uvals.size(); ++i) {
      const T& uval = uvals[i];
      const sort_pair_iter range_start = sorted_i;
      // we know there is at least one value
      do
        (*inverse)[sorted_i->index] = i;
      while(++sorted_i != sorted_end && sorted_i->value == uval);
      if(count)
        count->push_back(std::distance(range_start, sorted_i));
    }
  }
  if(count && ! inverse) {
    sort_pair_iter range_start = sorted_begin;
    for(const T& uval: uvals) {
      sort_pair_iter range_end =
        std::find_if(std::next(range_start), sorted_end,
                     [&uval](const sort_pair& i) -> bool {
                       return i.value != uval;
                     });
      count->push_back(std::distance(range_start, range_end));
      range_start = range_end;
    }
    /*
     * We could use equal_range or a custom version based on an
     * exponential search to reduce the number of comparisons.
     * The reason we don't use equal_range is because it has worse
     * performance in the worst case (uvals.size() == sorted.size()).
     * We could make a heuristic and dispatch between both implementations
     */
  }
  return uvals;
}
```

The trick is to implement something resembling np.argsort. Everything else follows naturally. The inverse mapping is a bit tricky but not too hard when you do a pen-and-paper version of it first.

### unordered_map

We could also use unordered_map. That reduces the complexity to something like O(n) + O(m log(m)) for n entries with m unique values with sorting and O(n) without sorting the unique values.

But that involves a ton of temporary allocations if the number of unique values not much smaller than n. This issue can be resolved by switching to a hash map implementation such as [robin_hood](https://github.com/martinus/robin-hood-hashing) that uses a flat hash map as long the key-value pair is at most 6 size_t large, by default.

However, one should not underestimate the sheer performance of a hash map, even a mediocre one such as std::unordered_map. Here is a simple version that works well in practice.

```
#ifdef USE_ROBIN_HOOD
# include <robin_hood.h>
#else
# include <unordered_map>
#endif

template<class T, class Iterator>
std::vector<T>
unordered_unique(Iterator first, Iterator last,
                 std::vector<std::size_t>* index=nullptr,
                 std::vector<std::size_t>* inverse=nullptr,
                 std::vector<std::size_t>* count=nullptr)
{
#ifdef USE_ROBIN_HOOD
  using index_map = robin_hood::unordered_map<T, std::size_t>;
#else
  using index_map = std::unordered_map<T, std::size_t>;
#endif
  using map_iter = typename index_map::iterator;
  using map_value = typename index_map::value_type;
  for(std::vector<std::size_t>* arg: {index, inverse, count})
    if(arg)
      arg->clear();
  std::vector<T> uvals;
  index_map map;
  std::size_t cur_idx = 0;
  for(Iterator i = first; i != last; ++cur_idx, ++i) {
    const std::pair<map_iter, bool> inserted =
      map.emplace(*i, uvals.size());
    map_value& ival = *inserted.first;
    if(inserted.second) {
      uvals.push_back(ival.first);
      if(index)
        index->push_back(cur_idx);
      if(count)
        count->push_back(1);
    }
    else if(count)
      (*count)[ival.second] += 1;
    if(inverse)
      inverse->push_back(ival.second);
  }
  return uvals;
}
```

I tested this with N = 1 million random int entries modulo M. M=N (~600,000 unique values), the Robin-Hood version beats the sorting version. With M=N/10 (~100,000 unique values), even the std version beats the sorting version.

Comment: This solution works for me, thank you. In my application, the number of different items is quite high (between 1/10 and 1/5 of the total number of entries), so like Jerôme Richard said, your solution is thus probably better for me that the one based on hash maps proposed by Dúthomhas. I have performances very similar to the ones I have with numpy

Comment: I also want to add that the items of the container in my application are coordinates (2D or 3D vectors typically). To sort them in the algorithm you've proposed, I just use std::lexicographical_compare as comparison operator, this is very efficient.

Answer (score 2):

A `std::map` combined with a `std::vector` gives you all the information you want.

```
#include <map>
#include <vector>

template <typename Container>
auto unique_map( const Container & xs )
-> std::map <typename Container::value_type, std::vector <std::size_t> >
{
  decltype(unique_map(xs)) S;

  std::size_t n = 0;
  for (const auto & x : xs)
  {
    S[ x ].push_back( n++ );
  }

  return S;
}
```

Now you can convert any container to a sorted `std::map` where:

- each key is a unique element from the original container `xs`
- each value is a `std::vector` listing indices into `xs`

If you wish to reconstruct `xs` from the mapping, you can do so easily enough:

```
#include <numeric>

template <typename UniqueMap>
auto rebuild_from_unique_map( const UniqueMap & um )
-> std::vector <typename UniqueMap::key_type>  // <std::size_t>
{
  decltype(rebuild_from_unique_map(um)) xs;
  if (um.size())
  {
    xs.resize( std::accumulate( um.begin(), um.end(), (std::size_t)0, 
        []( auto n, auto p ) { return n + p.second.size(); } ) );
    for (const auto & m : um)
      for (const auto & n : m.second)
        xs[n] = m.first;                       // index++
  }
  return xs;
}
```

If you really, really want that list of indices instead (`return_inverse`) you can get it by changing the commented lines as indicated and adding a `std::size_t index = 0;` before the nested loop.

Here’s a toy to play with it. Just concatenate the three code snippets in this post and compile. You’ll need Boost for the `irange`.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <boost/range/irange.hpp>
#include <cmath>
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main( int argc, char ** argv )
{
  std::vector <int> xs( argc-1, 0 );
  std::transform( argv+1, argv+argc, xs.begin(), []( auto s ) { return std::stoi( s ); } );

  auto width = std::setw( 3 + (int)std::log10( *std::max_element( xs.begin(), xs.end() ) ) );

  std::cout << xs.size() << " integers";
  std::cout << "\nvalue:  "; for (auto x : xs)                         std::cout << " " << width << x;
  std::cout << "\nindex: ["; for (auto n : boost::irange( xs.size() )) std::cout << " " << width << n;
  std::cout << " ]\n";

  auto ys = unique_map( xs );

  std::cout << "\n" << ys.size() << " unique integers";
  std::cout << "\nsorted:"; for (auto y : ys) std::cout << " " << width << y.first;

  std::cout << "\n\n";
  for (const auto & y : ys)
  {
    std::cout << width << y.first << " appears " << y.second.size() << " times at [";
    for (const auto & n : y.second) std::cout << " " << n;
    std::cout << " ]\n";
  }
  
  std::cout << "\nrebuilt:"; for (auto x : rebuild_from_unique_map( ys )) std::cout << " " << width << x;
  std::cout << "\n";
}
```

Compile with something like:

- `cl /EHsc /W4 /Ox /std:c++17 /I C:\boost\include a.cpp`
- `clang++ -Wall -Wextra -pedantic-errors -O3 -std=c++17 a.cpp`
- etc

The toy is ***not*** tolerant of bad input: make sure that you give it at least one argument and that all arguments are integers. You can change it to work over any arbitrary `std::string` if you wish: just adjust the first three statements in `main()` to fill `xs` with strings and compute `width` correctly.

Here’s me playing with it on my Windows box:

`a 2 -1 2 4 -1 2 3 7 -1 2 0 5`

```
12 integers
value:     2  -1   2   4  -1   2   3   7  -1   2   0   5
index: [   0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10  11 ]

7 unique integers
sorted:  -1   0   2   3   4   5   7

 -1 appears 3 times at [ 1 4 8 ]
  0 appears 1 times at [ 10 ]
  2 appears 4 times at [ 0 2 5 9 ]
  3 appears 1 times at [ 6 ]
  4 appears 1 times at [ 3 ]
  5 appears 1 times at [ 11 ]
  7 appears 1 times at [ 7 ]

rebuilt:   2  -1   2   4  -1   2   3   7  -1   2   0   5
```

`a 1 1 1`

```
3 integers
value:     1   1   1
index: [   0   1   2 ]

1 unique integers
sorted:   1

  1 appears 3 times at [ 0 1 2 ]

rebuilt:   1   1   1
```

`a 3 1 2`

```
3 integers
value:     3   1   2
index: [   0   1   2 ]

3 unique integers
sorted:   1   2   3

  1 appears 1 times at [ 1 ]
  2 appears 1 times at [ 2 ]
  3 appears 1 times at [ 0 ]

rebuilt:   3   1   2
```

Good question!

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the two current great posted answers, there are some important point to take into account in order to write an efficient implementation.

First of all, using a **hash-map can be very efficient** if the number of different items is small so that the hash-map can **fit in cache**. Classical sorting algorithm (eg. introsort/mergesort/heapsort) tends to be significantly slower because of the `log n` factor in the complexity. However, when the number of different items is big, a sort is generally much faster since the *unpredictable random-like hash-map access pattern in RAM* can be very expensive: each access can be as slow as the RAM **latency** (typically 40~100 ns).

Additionally, sort implementations can be vectorized using **SIMD instructions** (see [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1704.08579.pdf) for AVX-512 and [there](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC8627236/) for SVE) and parallelized using **multithreading**. This is especially true in this case since `np.unique` is generally applied on numbers. C++17 provides parallel algorithms (PSTL) including parallel sorts. Numpy sorting algorithms have recently been improved to use AVX-512 resulting in an order of magnitude faster execution. Alternatively, an `O(n)` radix sort can be used to efficiently sort small array with short-sized keys (eg. 4-bytes).

Moreover, **not all hash-map implementations are equivalent in term of performance**. The STL `std::unordered_map` tends to be pretty slow. This is due to restrictions in the C++ standard (about the invalidation of iterators) that (almost) force the STL not to use an [open addressing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_addressing) strategy. Instead, STL implementations generally use linked lists to solve hash conflicts and this cause slow allocation as described by @Homer512. The thing the fastest existing hash-map implementations mainly use open addressing. For example, [hopscotch hashing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hopscotch_hashing) provide good performance with some interesting guarantees (eg. good performance when the [load factor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table#Key_statistics) is close to 90~100%). [Tessil](https://tessil.github.io/2016/08/29/benchmark-hopscotch-map.html) has provided a very interesting benchmark about several hash-map implementations and has written very fast implementations (generally much faster than the one of the mainstream STL implementations).

`std::map` is usually implemented using a [red-black tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red%E2%80%93black_tree). It is written in a pretty efficient way in mainstream STL implementations. However, the **allocator** used by default is clearly not optimized for this use-case. Indeed, the number of nodes to be inserted is bounded. Thus, one can use a [monotonic allocator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/monotonic_buffer_resource) to speed up the computation. An optimized implementation can even use few simple big arrays with *no additional allocation*.

Finally, note that `np.unique` provides the **index of the first unique value** and not all of them. This enable further optimisations. For example, no `std::vector` is needed for the `std::map`-based implementation of @Dúthomhas resulting in a smaller memory footprint and probably higher performance.