# Find the unique sorted values of a vector and also indexes of the sorted vector to regenerate the original vector

Tags: c++, vector, unique

Suppose we have a vector like

```
a = {2,2,2,1,7,7,7,5,5}
```

I wish to get a sorted vector of unique elements which in this case gives

```
b = {1,2,5,7}
```

I also wish to get a vector of indexes of this sorted vector that reconstructs the initial vector:

```
c = {1,1,1,0,3,3,3,2,2}
```

Here b[x] for each element x in c returns the original vector a.

```
{ b[1],b[1],b[1],b[0],b[3],b[3],b[3],b[2],b[2] } = { 2,2,2,1,7,7,7,5,5 }
```

I wish to write an efficient algorithm in C++ to give me vectors b and c, given a vector a.

I have implemented a brute force solution below:

```
    std::vector<int> vector_a{ 2,2,2,1,7,7,7,5,5 };

    std::vector<int> vector_b(vector_a); 
    std::sort(vector_b.begin(), vector_b.end());
    std::vector<int>::iterator ip;

    ip = std::unique(vector_b.begin(), vector_b.end());
    vector_b.resize(std::distance(vector_b.begin(), ip));

    std::vector<int> vector_c;

    for (int i = 0; i < vector_a.size(); ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < vector_b.size(); ++j) {
            if (vector_a[i] == vector_b[j]) {
                vector_c.push_back(j);
            }
        }
    }
```

Is there a way I can implement a more efficient solution with complexity lesser than O(m*n)?

Comment: Sounds like an interesting project. What is your actual question?

Comment: what did you try? You'd be surprised how often searching the words helps to find the right algorithms. It is `std::sort` and `std::unique`. Only to get the indices a bit extra work is needed

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number I have implemented a brute force solution using std::sort and std::unique. I have added that that to the question.

Comment: @NathanPierson I am trying to implement fuzzy image contrast enhancement

Comment: ok now we are just missing a question. Whats wrong with the solution you have already?

Comment: I feel my solution is inefficient. Since I am working with images with typical resolution of 1024*1024, my vector_a has around 1 million values and vector_b has 256 possible pixel values(0-255). Hence I was wondering if there is a solution better than the bruteforce one I have implemented.

Answer (score 3):

I would use a map of vectors or lists. The index would be the unique value, and the value would be the *list* of indices in the original vector.

It can be built in one single pass (complexity O(n)) and can in turn build the `b` and `c` vectors in one single pass (again complexity O(n))

Possible code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> a { 2,2,2,1,7,7,7,5,5 };
    std::map<int, std::vector<int> > m;
    for (int i = 0; i < a.size(); i++) {
        m[a[i]].push_back(i);
    }
    std::vector<int> b(m.size()), c(a.size());
    int i = 0;
    for (auto& it : m) {
        for (int j : it.second) {
            c[j] = i;
        }
        b[i++] = it.first;
    }
    std::cout << "b: " << b[0];
    for (int i = 1; i < b.size(); i++) std::cout << ", " << b[i];
    std::cout << "\nc: " << c[0];
    for (int i = 1; i < c.size(); i++) std::cout << ", " << c[i];
    std::cout << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

It gives as expected:

```
b: 1, 2, 5, 7
c: 1, 1, 1, 0, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2
```

---

After a second thought, the complexity should be slightly more than O(n) because inserting or searching in a `std::map` is not constant but is O(log(n)). But is should still be at most O(n*log(n))...

Comment: Thank you for your clear explanation and awesome solution. I have implemented it and It resulted in a big speedup for my project.

Comment: As indicated by OP in a comment, the number of values if less than `M = 256`, independent of `n`. Insertion in the map should be `O(log M) = O(1)`.  So your method is indeed O(N).

Answer (score 1):

What you want is what [`numpy.unique(a, return_inverse=True)`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.unique.html) returns in Python. I've found similar questions here: [C++ equivalent of numpy.unique on std::vector with return_index and return_inverse](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70868307/5754656), [Find the indices and inverse mapping of a unique vector](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41797338/5754656).

Here's a strategy on how to accomplish this:

- Generate [0, `a.size()`) in a vector, *i*
- Sort *i* based on the value in vector `a` at the given index
- Find the unique values by iterating over *i* and finding the indices whose item in `a` are different from the index before (including the first). This is similar to the `std::unique` algorithm.
- Find the "inverse indices" by iterating over *i* and assigning each index of the inverses by a counter that increments when there is a new unique value. This incrementing counter corresponds exactly to indices in the unique vector.

(The last two steps can be done together).

Here is an example:

```cpp
template<typename T>
struct unique_indices {
    std::vector<T> uniques;
    std::vector<std::size_t> inverse_indices;
};

template<typename T, typename Cmp = std::less<T>>
unique_indices<T> sort_unique(const std::vector<T>& v, Cmp&& cmp = {}) {
    unique_indices<T> result;

    // generate indices
    std::vector<std::size_t> sorted_indices(v.size());
    std::iota(sorted_indices.begin(), sorted_indices.end(), std::size_t{0});

    // sort based on indices
    // (Could want std::stable_sort here if you care about which exact
    //  item is copied into `unique`, but doesn't matter for `int` with `std::less`)
    std::sort(sorted_indices.begin(), sorted_indices.end(), [&](std::size_t i, std::size_t j) {
        return cmp(v[i], v[j]);
    });

    // get unique values + set inverse indices
    // (similar to std::unique algorithm)
    auto first = sorted_indices.begin();
    auto last = sorted_indices.end();
    if (first == last) return result;  // v was empty

    result.inverse_indices.resize(v.size());

    std::size_t unique_index = 0;
    result.uniques.push_back(v[*first]);
    result.inverse_indices[*first] = unique_index;

    while (++first != last) {
        if (cmp(result.uniques.back(), v[*first])) {
            // new value
            ++unique_index;
            result.uniques.push_back(v[*first]);
        }
        result.inverse_indices[*first] = unique_index;
    }

    return result;
}
```

```cpp
std::vector<int> vector_a = {2,2,2,1,7,7,7,5,5};
auto [vector_b, vector_c] = sort_unique(vector_a);
// vector_b == {1,2,5,7}
// vector_c == {1,1,1,0,3,3,3,2,2}
```

O(N lg N) runtime and O(N) extra space needed.
Your original solution was O(N lg N + N M) time also with O(N) extra space.

(Where N = `a.size()` and M is the number of unique values in a)

Comment: Thank you for your solution. I tried it and it worked. However I found it a bit difficult to understand as my main language is python and I am porting code from python to c++. To understand my code better in the future, I have gone ahead with the answer provided by @Serge Ballesta. Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

You indicated in a comment that in your use case, all values are in between [0, 255].

This allows to implement a variant of counting sort. Three steps:

1. Mark which values are used (array `values`): `values[a[i] = 1`.
2. looping over array `values`, add relevant ones in the vector `unique`, and at the same time associate each value to the corresponding index of the vector
3. Looping over the input array `a[]`, directly find the corresponding index `values[a[i]]`, and add this index in the vector `indexes`.

Total complexity: O(n)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <array>
#include <utility>

#define NMAX 256

void print (const std::vector<int> &v, const std::string& mes = "") {
        std::cout << mes;
        for (int i: v) {
                std::cout << i << " ";
        }
        std::cout << "\n";
}

std::pair<std::vector<int>, std::vector<int>> sort_unique (const std::vector<int> &a) {
    int n = a.size();
    std::vector<int> unique, indexes (n);
    std::array<int, NMAX> values;
    values.fill (0);
    unique.reserve (NMAX);
    for (auto& x: a) {
        values[x] = 1;
    }
    int cpt = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < NMAX; ++i) {
        if (values[i] == 0) continue;
        values[i] = cpt++;
        unique.push_back(i);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        indexes[i] = values[a[i]];
    }
    return {unique, indexes};
}

int main() {
    std::vector<int> a = {2,2,2,1,7,7,7,5,5};
    auto [unique, indexes] = sort_unique (a);
    print (a, "input: ");
    print (unique, "unique values: ");
    print (indexes, "indexes: ");
    return 0;
}
```